# Python/ Pygame: Unsure where to add new lines of code

Tags: python, pygame

I just got my newest code working but now I need to add the player hit box/rect and I have previously messed this up when entering new code so I don't know where to insert it.

Here is my code and what needs to be entered:
[image: Python Conference code]
Here is my code already:

```
# This just imports all the Pygame modules 
import pygame 
import time 

pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480)) 
pygame.display.set_caption('St.Patrick game') 

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048) 
pygame.mixer.music.load('Jake Kaufman - Shovel Knight - Specter of Torment OST - 02 From the Shadows (Plains of Passage).mp3') 
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0) 

image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png') 
# initialize variables 
image_x = 0 
image_y = 0 



while 1: 
    clock.tick(30) 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
            pygame.mixer.music.stop(282) 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: 
            pygame.quit() 
            pygame.mixer.music.stop(282) 


    image_x += 0 

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed() 

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]: 
        image_x -= 10 
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
        image_x += 10 
    if key[pygame.K_UP]: 
        image_y -= 10 
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
        image_y += 10 

    screen.fill((200, 200, 200))

    screen.blit(image, (image_x, image_y))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: If you don't know where to insert your code it means you don't know what your code is doing.

Comment: I know what the code does but I'm not sure where to insert the new code.

Comment: [You can do some relevant reading here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: if you don't know where to put code then you have to go back and learn all again.

Comment: don't put screenshot with code or error message - always put it as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick and direct answer to your question is that classes can be added anywhere in your code before you use them (generally in the beginning without being nested under anything else) and then you'd create it later in your code (but outside of your game loop) with a `player = Player()` call.

It looks like you might be starting with programming and running into OO for the first time. As for the longer answer, I can't tell you a general formula of "where new code goes", but gathering from the nature of your question, I more or less agree with one of the existing comments that you should probably do some reading on classes and object oriented programming. When it comes to writing code, every situation is nuanced and different. There's a lot of depth to the subject of Object-Oriented programming (classes), but knowing everything isn't necessary to be effective at using classes. Without basic fundamental knowledge of how classes and instances and OO work, you'll be prone to making lots of mistakes or mimicking conventions, rather than reliably designing or copying new code.

A reference document can be a bit overwhelming when you're starting out. I would recommend just Googling things like "Python OO crash course" just to get your feet wet. You'll find higher-level things like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A0gaXfM1UN0

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the code a bit and reading some things as mentioned up above I came to this as the answer:

```
# This just imports all the Pygame modules 
import pygame 
import time

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super(Player, self).__init__(*groups)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png')
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((320, 240), self.image.get_size())

    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= 10
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += 10
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= 10
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += 10

pygame.init() 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480)) 
pygame.display.set_caption('St.Patrick game') 

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048) 
pygame.mixer.music.load('Jake Kaufman - Shovel Knight - Specter of Torment OST - 02 From the Shadows (Plains of Passage).mp3') 
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0) 

image = pygame.image.load('Sprite-01.png') 
# initialize variables 
image_x = 320
image_y = 240

while 1: 
    clock.tick(30) 
    for event in pygame.event.get(): 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
            pygame.quit() 
            pygame.mixer.music.stop(282) 
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: 
            pygame.quit() 
            pygame.mixer.music.stop(282) 


    image_x += 0 

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed() 

    if key[pygame.K_LEFT]: 
        image_x -= 10 
    if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: 
        image_x += 10 
    if key[pygame.K_UP]: 
        image_y -= 10 
    if key[pygame.K_DOWN]: 
        image_y += 10 

    screen.fill((200, 200, 200))
    screen.blit(image, (image_x, image_y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```